# Prove the map $\Phi:G\to\operatorname{Aut}G$ with $g\mapsto (x\mapsto g^{-1}xg)$ is an homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra

According to this [article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupHomomorphism.html),

> A group homomorphism is a map $f:G \rightarrow H$ between two groups
>   such that the operation is preserved: $f(g_{1}g_{2}) = f(g_{1})f(g_{2})$ for all $g_{1}, g_{2} \in G$, where the product on the left-hand side is in $G$ and on the right-hand side is $H$.

***Question***

Let G be a group and let $Aut(G)$ be the group of automorphisms of G.

(a) For any $g \in G$ define $\phi_{g} : G \rightarrow G$ by $\phi_{g}(x)=g^{-1}xg$.  Check that $\phi_{g}(x)$ is an automorphism.

(b) Consider the map

$\Phi : G \rightarrow Aut(G)$

$g \mapsto \phi_{g}$

Check that $\Phi$ is a homomorphism.

***My Attempt***

I did the first part.

Now, I need to do the second part of this problem.  Here is my attempt for the second problem.

Observe that if we evaluate $\Phi$ at $gh$ with arbitrary $x$, then:

$\Phi(gh) = \phi_{gh}(x) = (gh)^{-1}x(gh) = h^{-1}(g^{-1}xg)h = h^{-1}\phi_{g}(x)h = \phi_{h}(\phi_{g}(x))$.

The problem is that I'm stuck with this part.  I think that the operation of that $\Phi$ would be the composition of two functions.

Another thought: It would not make sense to say that:

$\Phi(gh) = \Phi(g)\Phi(h)$

because,

$\Phi (gh) = h^{-1}g^{-1}xgh$

But

$\Phi(g) = g^{-1}xg$

$\Phi(h) = h^{-1}xg$

$\Phi(g)\Phi(h) = g^{-1}xgh^{-1}xh$

The problem is that G is not assumed to be abelian (Well, if it is, then the equality holds.).  Then, we can't take the product of $\Phi$'s to match with $\Phi_{gh}$.  If I'm right, the solution to the second part of this problem is unlike the one to the first part of this problem.

Any comments or suggestions?

Comment: Please, make titles less subjective and more informative.

Comment: You didn't happen to mean $\phi_g(x)=gxg^{-1}$ did you, *conjugation* by $g$? Then you would be able to show that $\Phi(g)=\phi_g$ is a homomorphism. As it stands, I don't think you can show what you want for a general group $G$.

Comment: Actually, it's the function given based on the assignment I need to work on.  Usually, the function is $\phi_{g}(x) = gxg^{-1}$, but my instructor gives us this $\phi_{g}(x) = g^{-1}xg$ which makes the problem seem more intriguing.

Comment: Intriguing perhaps, but sadly the problem is impossible as you've stated it. (Also, you need to add @NAME if you want people commenting here to be notified)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is an antihomomorphism, as you have shown. This is because you're using conjugation by $g^{-1}$.

You should actually be looking at the function $\Phi$ that maps an element $g\in G$ to a *function*, namely that who sends $x$ to $gxg^{-1}$. So we can write it as $g\mapsto \phi_g$ where $\phi_g(x)=gxg^{-1}$.

The question is whether this is an homomorphism. So take $h,g\in G$. Then $\Phi(hg)$ is a function that maps $x$ to $$(hg) x(hg)^{-1}=h(gxg^{-1})h^{-1}$$ But this can be seen to be the composition of the function $\phi_h$ that sends $x\mapsto hxh^{-1}$ with that which sends $x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$, because $$\phi_h\circ \phi_g(x)=h(g xg^{-1})h^{-1}$$
It follows that $$\Phi(hg)=\phi_{hg}=\phi_h\circ \phi_g=\Phi(h)\circ \Phi(g)$$
Remember that our group operation in $\rm Aut $ is composition of functions.

Comment: The function defined by the OP is $\phi_g(x)=g^{-1}xg$, not $gxg^{-1}$.

Comment: @WarrenMoore Yes, I added something.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Your response for the problem with the usual function is correct.  However, for the given problem I have, when I checked with this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antihomomorphism), it says that an antihomomorphism is a homomorphism.  What do you think about this?  Would you disagree with this?

Comment: @WarrenMoore Oh.  I was confused between $Y$ and $Y^{op}$.  I have a question: What is the difference between these notations?  Is it that the operation is reverse for the group $Y$?

Comment: @NasuSama Yes, we define $a\times b=b\cdot a$ where $\cdot$ is the original product in $G$.

Comment: @user50229 Where am I being rude? I don't think I have been rude, but I am sorry if that is what it felt like. I guess we can agree that any sane algebra instructor knows the difference between an homomoprhism and an antihomomorphism.

Comment: @user50229 Where is he being rude from his response? I don't see this happening, including the one you thought is rude. Please don't get into too much "fight".

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I think you are confusing the function $\Phi$ with $\phi$. We have $\phi_g: x \mapsto g^{-1}xg$, but $\Phi: g \mapsto \phi_g$.

But actually using the function $\phi$ as defined, I think we get an antihomomorphism so that $\Phi(gh) = \Phi(h)\Phi(g)$. Using $\phi_g = gxg^{-1}$ would give the homomorphism.

Comment: Haven't you just shown that $\Phi(gh)=\Phi(h)\Phi(g)$? Not that $\Phi(gh)=\Phi(g)\Phi(h)$?

Comment: Really?  Is that even true?  Did I finish the work, or did I try that in other way around and not get the equality?

Comment: @Warren Yes you are right, I think the homomorphism is when $\phi_g = gxg^{-1}$. In this case I think $\Phi$ is an antihomomorphism.

Comment: Yes I agree. The conjugation map is defined as $g\mapsto gxg^{-1}$, which isn't was is defined in the OP's question...

Answer (score 2):

Put $\Phi:g\longmapsto \phi_{g^{-1}}$

Comment: I don't see the point here.

Comment: @NasuSama The point is that if you replace $g^{-1}xg$ by $gxg^{-1}=(g^{-1})^{-1}x(g^{-1})$ you **do** get an homomorphism.

Comment: The point is that this is how $\Phi$ *must* be defined in order to get a homomorphism $G \to \operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

Comment: Yes, the point of this is to make the function homomorphism. :D

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main problem is the way the internal operation in $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is define.

Let $*:\operatorname{Aut}(G) \times \operatorname{Aut}(G) \to \operatorname{Aut}(G)$  be an internal operation in $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$, where $f*g:=g \circ f$. It's easy to show that $(\operatorname{Aut}(G), *)$ is a group.

Now, if we do the same reasoning, we get:

$$
\Phi(gh) = \phi_{gh}(x) = (gh)^{-1}x(gh) = h^{-1}(g^{-1}xg)h = h^{-1}\phi_{g}(x)h = \phi_{h}(\phi_{g}(x))=(\phi_{h}\circ\phi_{g})(x)
$$

But then, we have that $(\phi_{h}\circ\phi_{g})(x)=\phi_{g}*\phi_{h}=\Phi(g)*\Phi(h)$. Which means that $\Phi$ is a group homomorphism.